# Are all Adobe CS3 and CS4 programs compatible with windows 7 home premium

Tags: windows-7, windows, compatibility

*Are all Adobe CS3 and CS4 programs compatible with Windows 7 Home Premium?*

I have doubt that maybe it will not work?  Can you tell me if it works?

and also another question: are all programs in vista works in Windows 7 , (especially the games)?

Comment: Pick a question and don't throw everything into the one post. Second is way too general and unspecific since it varies.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a compatibility page where you can plug in the software that you're inquiring about:

> http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/default.aspx